# WPF text StringFormat as DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, string-formatting, dynamicresource

So i have this `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0:N2}%}"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="{DynamicResource ProgressBarForegroundColor}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFontFamily}"
    FontSize="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFontSize}"/>
```

And i want to be able to control this `String Format` from `N2` to `N1` etc. so i created this :

```
<system:String x:Key="ProgressBarStringFormat">N2</system:String>
```

Usage:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0:ProgressBarStringFormat}%}"
```

And in my `Progress-Bar` instead of seen the `Value` i only see `ProgressBarStringFormat` text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have anything but a literal for a property of a Binding. But if you're willing to use a ContentControl or a Label instead of a TextBlock, you can stick a DynamicResource or a Binding on the `ContentStringFormat` property:

```
<Label
    Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn}"
    ContentStringFormat="{DynamicResource ProgressBarStringFormat}"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="{DynamicResource ProgressBarForegroundColor}"
    TextElement.FontFamily="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFontFamily}"
    TextElement.FontSize="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFontSize}"
    />
```